# TF-IDF and Rocchio classification in Introduction to Information Retrieval

Tags: classification, information-retrieval

I'm looking at table 14.1 from [Vector Space Classification](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/14vcat.pdf) (chapter at link) in Introduction to Information Retrieval which Example 14.1 says "shows the tf-idf vector representations of the five documents in Table 13.1 using the formula `(1 + log tf) * log(4/df)` if `tf > 0`.  Yet, when I look at Table 14.1, it does not appear that this TF-IDF formula is applied to the document vectors.

The documents from table 13.1 are:

```
1: Chinese Beijing Chinese
2: Chinese Chinese Shanghai
3: Chinese Macao
4: Tokyo Japan Chinese
```

and the term weights for the vectors in Table 14.1 are:

```
vector Chinese Japan Tokyo Macao Beijing Shanghai
d1     0       0     0     0     1.0     0
d2     0       0     0     0     0       1.0
d3     0       0     0     1.0   0       0
d4     0       0.71  0.71  0     0       0
```

If I apply the TF-IDF formula to the `Japan` dimension of `d4`, I get:

```
TF: 1 (term appears once in document 4)
DF: log(4 / 1) (term is present in only document 4)
TF-IDF Weight is thus: log(4) ~ .60
```

Why does my calculation outcome different from what is included in the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have computed tf-idf correctly. The text is a bit misleading when it says

> Table 14.1 shows the tf-idf vector representations of the five documents
>   in Table 13.1.

It is actually showing the  tf-idf vector representations *normalized to unit length*.

**The details:**
Document 4 has three words "Tokyo", "Japan" and "Chinese".
You correctly computed that the TF-IDF weights for both "Tokyo" and "Japan"
should be
log10(4) ≈ 0.60. "Chinese" is in all documents, so the IDF part 
of its weight is log(4/4) = 0 and the weight for "Chinese" is zero.
So the vector for document 4 is

```
Chinese Japan Tokyo Macao Beijing Shanghai
   0    0.60  0.60    0      0       0
```

But the length of this vector is sqrt(0.60^2 + 0.60^2) ≈ 0.85  To get a vector of unit length,  all components are divided by 0.85 giving the vector in the text

```
Chinese Japan Tokyo Macao Beijing Shanghai
   0    0.71  0.71    0      0       0
```

It may be worth noting that the reason that we use vectors of unit length is to adjust for documents of different lengths.  Without this adjustment,  long documents would generally match queries better than short documents.